# Can't install Azure Functions and Web Jobs extension

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have been trying to install the Azure Functions and Web Jobs extension, however installation fails. Looking through the error log it appears that the piece that isn't working is this:

```
Install Error : System.InvalidOperationException: Installation of Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools failed. To install this extension please install at least one of the following components: Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools
```

I think that the problem is that it is looking for itself with the wrong name (Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools instead of Microsoft Azure Web Jobs Tools). Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I have this exact problem. Did you find a solution, Thomas?

Comment: Thomas, I found a solution which may help. I had to uninstall all previous Azure related stuff under Programs and Features - in particular, the Azure Compute Emulator (it was informing me that this did not install correctly). I uninstalled VS2017, uninstalled Azure stuff via Programs and Features then reinstalled VS2017 with the Azure workload.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just had the same problem and the error was not very helpful :( Fixed it by installing the Azure Development "workload" from the Visual Studio Installer. After running the installer, you can choose to modify the installation and add this. It will actually come with the extension you're trying to install, oddly enough, but it will not be the latest version of it.

Here is an image which I hope helps:
[image: Image of the 15.3.5 Visual Studio installer with Azure Development workload circled.]

Comment: Chris' comment above is correct. For some reason it just didn't work for me the first time round. I uninstalled and then reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 and then installed the Azure development workflow and now I have the correct template